# Avoid rotation of EKEventEditViewController

Tags: ios7, uiinterfaceorientation, ekevent

How to avoid rotation of EKEventEditViewController? In my case I need to restrict it to Portrait only. Can we change the navigation controller of EKEventEditViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.

Create a subclass EKEventEditViewController, and in that class override

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
//Does not support anything other than portrait
   return NO;
}
```

Then in use that custom class instead of EKEventEditViewController.